# syntax error in trying to create new list

Tags: python, list, syntax-error

Just trying to write a function that gets clock hand angles, but getting an error where i try to create an empty list. It has worked on other scripts previously without any issues.

```
def gethandpos():
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    datetime.time(now.hour,now.minute,now.second)
    m=float(now.minute+now.second/60)
    h=float(now.hour+(m/60))
    hangle=math.fabs(((h*360)/12)-90)
    mangle=math.fabs(((m*360)/60)-90)
    sangle=(math.fabs((float((now.second*360)/60))-90)
    coords=[]
    coords.append((math.cos(math.radians(sangle)),math.sin(math.radians(sangle))))
    coords.append((math.cos(math.radians(mangle)),math.sin(math.radians(mangle))))
    coords.append((math.cos(math.radians(hangle)),math.sin(math.radians(hangle))))
    print coords
```

output:

```
coords=[]
     ^
syntax error: invalid syntax
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try it line by line in the console. Something will go wrong in the line before the `coords=[]` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sangle=(math.fabs((float((now.second*360)/60))-90)
       1         23     45              1   23   4
```

Comment: i was just trying to 'answer' it... site wont let me.. sorry. dumb mistake. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
sangle=(math.fabs((float((now.second*360)/60))-90)
```

has an additional opening parenthesis in the beginning.  Try

```
sangle = math.fabs(float(now.second * 360 / 60) - 90)
```

instead.

Python ignores linebreaks inside parentheses.  That's why the following line was interpreted as part of the assignment to `sangle`, leading to a syntax error.

I recommend to format your code in a more readable way:  use spaces around operators, don't use too many parentheses where they are unnecessary, split complex expression into multiple steps etc.